# TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

Quero apenas somar os valores que recebo no `input`, qual o problema com o código?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function calcula(){
 var soma = document.getElementsById('valor').value;
 var total =0;
 total+= soma;
 document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = total;
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>



<input type="text" name="valor">
<button id="calc" onclick="calcula()">Soma</button>

<h3 id="resultado"></h3>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse método é singular: `getElementById`

Comment: Se tem uma nova pergunta, faça ela em [ask]. Não edite a pergunta atual de forma que pode invalidar as respostas dadas. Cada problema, uma pergunta separada. O que você pode fazer para finalizar a pergunta é marcar a resposta como aceita. Veja como no [tour]. Depois disso também terá direito a votar em tudo que achar útil no site.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O problema está nessa linha. tem um S onde não devia:

```
var soma = document.getElementById('valor').value;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/DocumentValue.js).